# Why the new google places api is not synchronizing with build.gradle?

Tags: android, google-places-api

According to google's new places API ( https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start ). I have done everything mentioned at this link and enabled billing for my project but still I am unable to sync project.
The error is

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0:
Install Repository and sync project
```

I have updated `android sdk`, `play services` and `google repository` to the latest version.
I have searched for a lot on `stackoverflow` and other sites but there is no question available realted to this.

My app level `build.gradle` file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prisma.placesapidemo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0'
}
```

My project level `build.gradle` file is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Getting Started guide has the wrong dependency (despite it being correct on the [Migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_client_library)). As seen on [maven.google.com](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html), the actual dependency is:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

Note there is also a `:places-compat` dependency as well.